# In typescript, how do you express the type of an object where one of the fields is the name of the type?

Tags: typescript

I'm dealing with an event payload where the `event` field is a string, and the `data` field is conditional on the `event` field. I've made a representation that works but feels this isn't the canonical way:

```
type EventMap = {
  created: { created: string },
  updated: { updated: string }
}

type Payload<T extends keyof EventMap> = {
  event_id: string;
  event: T;
  data: EventMap[T];
};

type Payloads = Payload<'created'> | Payload<'updated'>
```

It feels like I should not be repeating `created` and `updated`. But of course `Payload<keyof EventMap>` isn't quite right since it will allow any combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like following:

```
type Payloads = { [K in keyof EventMap]: Payload<K> }[keyof EventMap]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAsgQzFAvFA3gWACgooBjAJwjWAgBMAuPMy6uxgZ2HIEtEBzKAF8ANERIBXMLVYMmk6TVmce-IUUFEioSFAAKaEABsA9mloAeACpQIADxqJa7KAGsIIYwDNYCZOjAAfNh4Yja+wAD63EpcvHwA3KEQ4YyWicRQCmiM8EioGADalgC66YLpWuDQ+kamTsG4UAUA0lC8ru5ePnn+xYw1JmbmzUGCBW4e3rl+GMWahAD0C1Da1QaD9TgDdeYA5BRUirtBAD566zu78jLH80srVee1Zs44BIvLJCQtbYgdk90ZmA+iEPl9wSRknkojEVAkiPcIV8ochGM10oikZlqNlAfkwC1SgjPl8NGCxhMutN8XNCERSMZEJwoLZ+hcXg1QpDwjDGLtbLtRBluXk+QcbkLwVlGO8scxDmwoLt2LsuWpCGT6YzmSA2c9NqDwSjItE+QLJciUkrrkcLSRpYasTbFcrVcL1ZrCAymcAoAAvPUbV6OkXIXlK81q418520QVqh2yrHixR8lVqsmCIA)

Or create the `Payloads` type from `EventMap` directly:

```
type Payloads = {
    [K in keyof EventMap]: {
        event_id: string;
        event: K;
        data: EventMap[K];
    }
}[keyof EventMap]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=18&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAsgQzFAvFA3gWACgooBjAJwjWAgBMAuPMy6uxgZ2HIEtEBzKAF8ANERIBXMLVYMmk6TVmce-IUUFEiAei1RQkKAAU0IADYB7NLQA8AFSgQAHjUS12UANYQQ5gGawEZHQwAD5sPG1dEghA4AB9biUuXj4AbkiSB1jGW3TCHUyFNEZ4JFQMAG1bAF08gsE8jP1oYzNLN3DWiytrAHIKKkVesIAfIxNum175GWHNQmbxtqt3HAJiTIqAaSheT28-ALLg6sZ1zIussoSklTSxS+jsqC28x5Iiktjg7dqHkg0hEEFS8Pn8pSCGGq81I5kQnCgjkYXXaqwiGye10SjF6jl6ogxV2QOIGswJF0+6PezEGbCgvXYvX+aiBMLhCJAyImqPC50yMSxslx+OZAuJ9JmQ3JhWoxSp70ldIZTMJgMBRFh8OAUAAXlzlh01qLYjccXjpZjxdMpGTmZS+Y9SYocYzmWqgA)

---

```
// works
const x: Payloads = {
    event_id: 'x',
    event: 'created',
    data: {
        created: 's'
    }
}

// works
const y: Payloads = {
    event_id: 'x',
    event: 'updated',
    data: {
        updated: 's'
    }
}

// error due to mixed updated and created
const z: Payloads = {
    event_id: 'x',
    event: 'updated',
    data: {
        created: 's'
    }
}
```